# how to install yum package on linux RHEL 4?

Tags: linux, vmware, yum, rhel

when i run  **root@localhost# yum install package_name** command on linux terminal it gives:

```
bash: yum: command not found
```

because i don't have yello update and modifier package install on my linux . for that i        mount my linux iso disc.and write command

```
root@localhost# cd /meida/RHEL_4/i386/ Disk/ 1/
root@localhost RHEL_4 i386 Disk 1# ls
```

but there is no package directory. and i didn't find any http url form downloading(wget) yum.x.x.x.rpm. i have linux RHEL 4 AS version installed. plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yum is not compatible with RHEL 4 (FOR RHN Stuff). They don't officially ship yum with rhel4 instead use legacy '`up2date`' utility. up2date is similar to yum but far less featured package management utility but good in dependency resolution. It resolves the packages dependencies in same way, yum do.

Anyway, You can get the rpm package here, http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel...oview/yum.html. Just download it and install using `rpm -ivh` command. don't expect, yum will download the packages from RHN. to sync with rhn you still have to use up2date.

Comment: yes it is not install on my system i have all ready run the command rpm -qa but yum rpm is not in the list

Comment: actually i don't have yum-x.x.x.noarch.rpm on my system and not even in my disk

Comment: given url for rpm package download http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel...oview/yum.html was not found on server